# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Blog"

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am getting above error which I am stuck I am a beginner of mongodb, expressjs

My Index.js:

```js
 const mongoose= require('mongoose')
 let modelspath ='./models'
fs.readdirSync(modelspath).forEach(function(file){
    if(~file.indexOf('.js')) 
    console.log(file)
    require(modelspath +'/' + file) //if block checks weather file ending with .js ext
})
```

my controller file

```js
const BlogModel = mongoose.model('Blog')
let testRoute = (req, res) => 
{
    console.log(req.params)
    res.send(req.params)
}
```

my model.blog.js file

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let blogSchema =new Schema(
    {
        blogId :{
            type: string,
            unique:true   
        },

mongoose.model('Blog',blogSchema);
```

my routing file

```js
const express =require('express')
//here we can find routees logic path
const control =require('./../controllers/controller')
let setRouter =(app) =>{
//here we are getting our logics and assigning for a Http verbs (get,post,put,del)
 app.get('/test/route/:param1/:param2',control.testRoute)
 app.get('/example',control.example)
//  app.post('/hello', control.postmethod)
}
module.exports={
    setRouter:setRouter
}
```

Can anyone help me out of this error

Comment: Where is your schema ? mongoDB couldn't find it

Comment: It's in my models file

Comment: try to include your model.blog.js in your index.js file

Comment: Sir,As you said its working fine for me but I am unable to notice what was error in my code As per my knowledge, for mongoose there is no need to write module exports so I have not set path for that .But the thing is in the mongoose file I have'nt written any module.exports and set my path in index.js and it is working fine How did the functionality working without exports Can you help me out in this?

Comment: mongoose needs schema named "blog" but he doesn't find it and error is thrown.
Solution of this problem is to include model.blog.js and so mongoose knows shema and can use it.